# Excel - Trying to compare two columns worth of data in separate sheets and if they match return a set of data from each sheet

Tags: excel

I have two sheets of data in the same workbook. If data from Sheet 1 column J, matches data from sheet 2 column F, then i want columns A-I from Sheet 1 + Column C from Sheet 2 added onto a third sheet

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for Excel O365.  Set `A2` to `=FILTER(Sheet1!J:J, (Sheet1!J:J <> "") * NOT(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet1!J2:J, Sheet2!F:F)))`

Then set `B2` to `=XLOOKUP(A2#,Sheet1!J:J,Sheet1!A:I)`

And set `K2` to `XLOOKUP(A2#,Sheet2!F:F,Sheet2!C:C)`